# Docker run doesn't start the container

Tags: .net, dockerfile

I have created a dotnet webapi service using dotnet core 5, built a docker image with the below Dockerfile and while running it get the below error message:

```
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.

Possible reasons for this include:

  * You intended to execute a .NET program:

      The application 'PlatformService.dll' does not exist.

  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:

      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.

      Install a .NET SDK from:

        https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "PlatformService.dll" ]
```

Can some one point out what exactly is missing here to run my image. BTW I am running this on Windows 10 machine.

Comment: This likely means a file named `PlatformService.dll` doesn't exist at that location. You could try listing the contents of the root directory by running this command: `docker run --rm --entrypoint ls <image-tag>`. That will help in identifying what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks Matt. The command lists all the dependent dlls along with entrypoint dll platformservice.dll

Comment: Infact I do see all the dlls in local bin folder present in the container.

Comment: Is the filename lowercase just as you've written in your comment? If so, then the Dockerfile needs to match the case. If you're targeting Linux containers, be aware that the Linux filesystem is case-sensitive.

Comment: Docker file name is 'Dockerfile' and it is located in the same path as csproj.

Comment: I'm referring to the filename of the DLL. That is case-sensitive if you're targeting Linux containers.

Comment: You are right @MattThalman the entrypoint dll was in camel case in the docker file, changing it to lowercase to match the dll name worked. 
Thanks a ton. Appreciate you taking time to help me out.

Comment: How can i mark this as ansawered and close this ticket? 
one more time :)

Answer (score 0):

This error will happen if the casing of the DLL name you're targeting in your Dockerfile doesn't match the casing of the file that exists on disk (this is only true for Linux). Be sure that `ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "PlatformService.dll" ]` uses a DLL name that matches the casing of the actual file.